# Adding Custom Metadata to TIFF file

Tags: .net, image, metadata, tiff

I am trying to encode and digitally sign a tiff image. We use PsiCom.dll (library provided by Medicare Australia to encode and sign images). So far so good.
What I am also trying to do is, add some metadata information to the tiff file (eg timestamp just before the file was encoded). At the moment this is being done by appending the timestamp information to the end of the file, and then removing the information that was appended when the image is decoded. here is some pseudocode that does this:

```
'

Read the image into a byte array
File.SetAttributes(ImagePath, FileAttributes.Normal)
Dim Temp() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath)


Dim DateKey() as Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") 

' copy into data array
Dim Data() As Byte = New Byte(((Temp.Length + (DateKey.Length + 1))) - 1) {}

Temp.CopyTo(Data, 0)

 'Temp now has the timestamp.
```

This is rather cumbersome at the decoding end, because one needs to know the exact number to bytes to remove off the end of the file. 
I do not know much about tiff files, and haven't worked on image files before, but with some reading I found that one could use custom tags within the tiff file. Can anyone please throw some light on this. I would ideally like to add metadata / custom tags in the key-value pair format, so that when I do have to remove this information, I can simply remove the entire key-value pair or just set the values to null. And most importantly I want to do this using .net and I cannot use third party dlls such as LibTiff.Net.
Regards,

Laavanya Lokkanathan

Comment: If you just want to add a timestamp, the TIFF Tag 306 (DATETIME) is already defined by the standard. Adding and removing custom tags to existing TIFF files with your own code is not that difficult, but it does take a fair amount of code to properly pick apart and reassemble a TIFF file while preserving all of the existing metadata. Please provide more details about what you need.